# Jenkins login issue with Tomcat server "Invalid login information. Please try again"

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I set up the `Jenkins` in my Windows machine (OS-Windows 10). I completed the setup and run the Jenkins and tested in the browser by hitting the `http://localhost:8080` (As the default port is 8080). So the standalone instance of Jenkins works fine with port number 8080. But when I try it with Tomcat server, I'm unable to login itself. Though It launches the Jenkins login page. Below is how I have tried so far-

1) I installed Jenkins and tested in the browser with `http://localhost:8080`. It runs fine. I can login with the default admin credentials.

2) I shutdown the Jenkins service by running the command `jenkins.exe stop`. Since `Tomcat` server does also run on the same port.

[image]

3) I installed `Tomcat` and hits the url `http://localhost:8080`. I can see the server's home screen.

4) I copied the `jenkins.war` file from the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` and deployed in `webapp` folder of `Tomcat` server. It says that `Jenkins` is up and running.

[image]

5) Now in the browser, when I hit the url `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`, I can see the Jenkins's login screen. I entered the same credential which were provided by Jenkins only(The default credentials- `Username:admin` and `Password:fcb77f29d0e34cabab385b74709e5f3c` from the file `initialAdminPassword`).

[image]

Now my query comes here. I can see the Jenkins login screen in both the cases (Jenkins Standalone instance and Jenkins with Tomcat). I enter the above credentials in both the cases, but the default credentials work with Jenkins Standalone only not with Tomcat.

[image]

What am I missing or what am I not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Check it out.

When I was running Jenkins with Tomcat server, I was trying the same credentials of Jenkins standalone. That was the reason, the authentication was getting failed every time I tried to install. So how I solved it? The Jenkins itself provides the user configurations details with Tomcat in order to keep Jenkins more secure. Check the below configuration which we need to add in `tomcat-users.xml` file.

[image]

So my `tomcat-users.xml` file looks like this -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="jenkins-admin" password="secret" roles="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```